# Azure DevOps Pipeline - Can I run different tasks based on time of day?

Tags: python, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, jobs

I have two python files in my repo. Using an azure pipeline, I want file1 to run at one specific hour of the day, and I want file2 to run at the top of the rest of the hours.

I currently have one job defined in the azure_pipeline.yml file, with one task being running file1. How do I adapt the job or task to run either file based on the above condition?

Comment: Why dont you use two different pipeline scripts with two different cron definitions? It would be very easy and also very flexibile

Comment: @erbg Do you have an example of that? I think that solution would be ideal. From what I've read, only one azure_pipeline.yml file is allowed. How can a second pipeline script be added?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I adapt the job or task to run either file based on the above condition?

You can use the schedule trigger and the `system.pipelinestarttime` variable to set the condition or if expression.

The format of the system.pipelinestarttime variable: `2022-06-30 03:13:20+00:00`

Here is an example:

```
schedules:
- cron: "   1 * * * *"
  displayName: Daily midnight build
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  always: true

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- ${{ if and(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule'), contains(variables['system.pipelinestarttime'], 'time for example: 3:14')) }}:
  - task: file 1

- ${{ else }}:
  - task: file 2
```

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Scheduled triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#scheduled-triggers) and [Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#contains)

**Updated:**

You can two separate pipelines to use the files .

Here is an example:

YAML 1:

```
schedules:
- cron: "   * 1 * * *"
  displayName: specific hour
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  always: true

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - task: file 1
```

YAML 2

```
schedules:
- cron: "   1 * * * *"
  displayName: Other hours
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  always: true

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - task: file 2
```

When you create the Pipelines, you can select the YAML file to create the pipeline.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to have two separate pipelines rather than one that checks the time?

Comment: Yes. Refer to my update in the answer

Answer (score 0):

As of my comment, you can create a second pipeline with other cron settings, it is really straightforward:

You can create as many Devops Build Pipelines you want within a repo.

If you go throw the normal Step of creating a Buid Pipeline, Azure Devops will create a new azure-pipelines-*.yml File (the first filename is azure-pipelines.yml)

[image: New Pipeline]

The default filename is azure-pipelines.yml but you can rename that file also in a second moment if you prefer:

[image: Project Settings]

Answer (score 0):

You can define two schedules in your pipeline and give them different DisplayName, then add the condition to your job or task

```
condition: eq(variables['Build.CronSchedule.DisplayName'], 'Schedule1')
```

see more at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/schedules-cron?view=azure-pipelines